# Why does my PHP to SMTP mailing script not work?

Tags: php, html, smtp, sendmail, smtpclient

I have a local instance of sendmail running on my machine, and am using a php script in order to send custom messages in order to run an internal anonymous suggestions application.
I currently use the following script:

```
<?php
$to      = '*to*';
$subject = '*subject*';
$message = '*message*';
$headers = 'From: *from*' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: *replyto*' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

I would like to be able to support HTML, which I would assume was the following:

```
<?php
$to      = '*to*';
$subject = '*subject*';
$message = '<html><a href="www.google.com">here</a></html>';
$headers = 'From: *from*' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Contesnt-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: *replyto*' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what the actual problem/error you're having is.  If this is a direct copy/paste, I see you have a typo: "Contesnt-type"

Comment: that was it! its always the simplest things

Answer (score 0):

I do this via these functions:

```
private function plaintext_version($text) {

return "--PHP-nextpart-".$this->random_hash
     ."\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\""
     ."\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit"
     ."\n$text";

} // EOF plaintext_version

private function HTML_version($html) {

return "--PHP-nextpart-".$this->random_hash."
Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$html
";
} // EOF HTML_version
```

Here's the "Send" function.  *Note that the Content-Type is "multipart/alternative" and a "boundary" is specified*; I create the boundary by concatenating "--PHP-nextpart-" with the output of a hashing function.

```
public function Send() {

  if (strlen($this->cc_to)) $this->headers .='Cc: '.$this->cc_to . "\r\n";

  if (strlen($this->bcc_to)) $this->headers .='Bcc: '.$this->bcc_to . "\r\n";

  if (strlen($this->reply_to)) $this->reply_to = $this->mail_from;


  $l_headers = 'From: '.$this->mail_from . "\r\n"
  .'Reply-To: '.$this->reply_to. "\r\n"
  .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()."\r\n";

  if (strlen($this->headers)) $l_headers .= $this->headers;

  $l_headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-nextpart-".$this->random_hash."\"";

  $mess = $this->plaintext_version($this->msg_text) . "\n\n". $this->HTML_version($this->html_version);

  if (strlen($this->to_name)) {
     $to = "\"".$this->to_name."\" <".$this->mail_to.">";
  } else {
     $to = $this->mail_to;
  }

  $sent = mail($to,$this->subject,$mess,$l_headers);
  if ($sent) return true;
  return false;

} //EOF Send()
```